# htaccess rewriterule for directory is changing the url in a undesireable way

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

***EDIT***
After a comment from Seth below, and heading to a helpful apache page [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html), I have found that VirtualHosts are the way to go for the following issue.
/edit

--**ORIGINAL POST**--
First, a little background on file setup. I am running a LAMP server that hosts multiple domains. I have staging and live sites on this server, under different directories under the web root.

examples
/webroot/live/site1/[public files]
/webroot/live/site2/[public files]

/webroot/stage/site1/[public files]
/webroot/stage/site2/[public files]

The domains for each of these go to the IP of the server, which points at the webroot directory. I have an .htaccess file there to load the appropriate content based on the http_host.

examples

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1-live.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /live/site1/$1 [PT,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1-stage.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stage/site1/$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

These work great for hitting the home page and any of the internal pages, even with the specific pages being like site1-live.com/view/123. Each site's htaccess handles those.

**My issue** (sorry it took so long to get here):

When I head to any subdirectory within a site, like www.site1-live.com/rss, the content loads just fine, but the URL changes to something like the following

```
http://www.site1-live.com/live/site1/rss/
```

Essentially showing the path from the webroot to the files.

How can I avoid this? I obviously want the url to remain www.site1-live.com/rss. Do I need an htaccess file inside the rss directory to block this somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So it only shows the root url when you visit a folder, not a file or page?

Comment: right, if I go to www.site1-live.com/somepage.php it stays as such. I'm thinking Seth's recommendation of virtual hosts will probably be the correct route though. I'm going to look into those.

Answer (score 0):

replace ^www with ^(.*)

then have the whole url in the second line www.yourdomain.com/live/...

Comment: And how exactly does that fix his problem?

Comment: misread your post. You should not use an htaccess for this at all. You should configure virtual hosts. Do you need instructions on how to do that?

Comment: I've heard about those... meant to look into them... yes Seth, that would be very helpful

Comment: actually yes, perfect. After the guidance of http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html things are working great. Thanks Seth!

Answer (score 0):

Doug,

why do you need the QSA flag?

Anyway, what is happening to you is that mod_index (or whatever is serving you directories) is redirecting you www.site1-live.com/rss (without the ending /) to the equivalent URL with the ending /.

If you don't use mod_alias or something list that on the rewritten URLs, removing the PT should work as you expect.

Comment: QSA preserves query strings appended to uri, it doesn't have anything to do with this as far as I can tell. I'd expect the behavior he describes when the [R] tag is used though..

Comment: yes, I would expect that from [R] as well, but he specifically state that he is using [PT]

Comment: on the other hand, if he is not using Mod_Alias or something similar, he should not need the PT anyway.

Comment: You're probably right about that. Not sure if that'd solve the problem but it's worth a shot.